# In Loki, who is in this photo at the bottom of this box?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, object-identification, loki-2021

In season 1 episode 1 of *Loki* series when Loki visits the TVA he sees

> a drawer full of Infinity Stones and many other artifacts.

I would like to know whose photo is present in the drawer.

> [image: The open drawer as described above with the photo circled]

Comment: I'm interested in the medal, which appears to be the [Legion of Honour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_of_Honour).  Why would the TVA be keeping one of those together with items of such other importance?  Is there someone particular in the Marvel universe to whom it could belong?  (Granted the other items are not treated with much importance by the TVA, but perhaps there's an out-of-universe reason for it being given such prominence).  Should this be asked as a separate question?

Comment: @eggyal I'd argue "super rare baseball card", "top military honor of a country", "stones that shape reality itself" are all roughly equally valuable, as far as the TVA is concerned.  They go in a drawer somewhere.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It appears to be a [T206 Honus Wagner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T206_Honus_Wagner) baseball card (or perhaps a reissue/reprint/variation). It is an incredibly rare baseball card, with only an estimated 60 still in existence.

They're considered one of the most valuable ([and most famous](https://www.cardboardconnection.com/card-t206-honus-wagner)) baseball cards in the world, with some cards having been sold in auctions for millions of dollars ($5.2 million!).

The distribution was cut short either because Wagner didn't want children to purchase cigarettes in order to get his card, or because he wanted more money. Either way the production was cut short - resulting in only a maximum of 200 cards released to the public.

It seems very appropriate to have such a rare card kept alongside (several) Infinity Stones (and in a drawer no less).

[image: Example of a 1909 T206 Honus Wagner, depicting Wagner wearing a grey Pittsburgh]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129724/discussion-on-answer-by-fez-in-loki-who-is-in-this-photo-at-the-bottom-of-this).