# What else is in the TVA's junk drawer?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, object-identification, loki-2021, time-variance-authority

In episode 1 of *Loki* when Loki visits the TVA he sees:

> [image: Junk Drawer]

From this question [Whose photo is this?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/250364/whose-photo-is-this) we can see that the TVA put multiple items of value (in our reality) into the drawer.

Can anybody identify any of the other items in the drawer?

Comment: I'm too lazy so here's [a reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/nwkfuf/loki_spoilerslets_deduce_all_the_items_in_tva/) for reference for anyone that wants to do this. Could be worthy of a community wiki answer as well.

Answer (score 8):

Here are a couple of higher-resolution screenshots:

> [image: A hand reaches into an open drawer, into a shallow grey tray filled with bright coloured rocks and other trinkets]
>  [image: Another view of the same drawer, but with the hand on the edge of the drawer so other contents can be seen]

I thought to check the "English [Audio Description]" audio track, but all it says is: "Loki's eyes fix on a tray of assorted gems inside the cluttered drawer."

A few of the items are "obvious" (from a still screenshot):

- The baseball card is a notoriously valuable [T206 Honus Wagner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T206_Honus_Wagner).
- As observed by Teridactyl-9000 on the Reddit thread: The white box is the right size for a reel-to-reel tape, and is labeled `Watergate-lost 18 min.` (or something like that; I'm not sure about `lost`, but the first word is definitely `Watergate`). This is [Rose Mary Woods' 18.5-minute gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nixon_White_House_tapes#The_18%C2%BD-minute_gap). The evidence tag is in shadow; all I can guess at is that again the first word is `WATERGATE`:

[image: Close up of a flat square white box, on top of which is a cardboard tag with a loop of twine attached]

- The medal is the badge of the French Legion of Honor. Its evidence tag very legibly reads "French Medal of Honor." The field at the bottom says something like "`AFB-TEN`", but actually that's probably just the identifier of the agent who placed the item into evidence, and unrelated to the identity of the medal itself. I tried and failed to find any (real-world) "lore" about someone who might have lost a Legion of Honor medal and/or vanished while wearing one.

[image: Another tag, legible this time, as described above]

- The poker chip is just a plain old Crown Company brand clay poker chip in the $5000 denomination. You can buy such chips in rolls of 25, e.g. [here](https://www.americangamingsupply.com/Crown-Casino-Clay-Poker-Chips-13.5g-5000-Dollar.aspx). I tried and failed to find any (real-world) "lore" about such a chip.

[image: red-rimmed poker chip with a $5000 amount on it]

- Someone in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/nwwgkx/loki_spoiler_a_mysterious_item_identified/) points out that the silver cross resembles the [Cross of Coronado](https://indianajones.fandom.com/wiki/Cross_of_Coronado) from *Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade*; but it's missing the *corpus* of Jesus (that is, the one in the drawer is a plain cross; the one from *Indiana Jones* was a crucifix).

Answer (score 4):

According to a [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/250376/what-else-is-in-the-tvas-junk-drawer#comment684992_250376) by TheLethalCarrot, here are a few of the items that were found in the drawer:

> 1. coiled engine head
> 2. TVA tag with "evidence", other words indecipherable
> 3. woven plate with 80s candy
> 4. handle of something, wooden, with golden hardware
> 5. another TVA tag
> 6. red coil of some kind
> 7. White frame serving as a plate for items
> 8. properly tagged French Medal of Honor
> 9. outside of frame to the left - metallic object, unidentified
> 10. outside of frame what appears to be a purple bracelet, futuristic
> 11. 5000 worth of a gamble chip
> 12. red sash
> 13. a gun and a medal (or something possibly joined)
> 14. four 80's styled glass marbles for children
> 15. a baseball card
> 16. TVA Tag that says: "Lot of early i..." and in the next line "Baseball cards.."
> 17. Byzantine styled metallic cross, with jewels on it (most likely to be Orthodox)
> 18. magnifying glass with wooden frame; appears to be older
> 19. Multiple various infinity stones
> 20. something that appears to be a handgun
> 21. cable under the white frame
> 22. a white object with the KIKA word on it

*(Please note that I made some slight corrections, so the answer on Reddit differs slightly.)*

Comment: #6 appears to be an miniature  arc reactor like Tony Stark's

Comment: #15 T206 Honus Wagner baseball card (from the linked to question)

Comment: These are just descriptions, and as pointed out on Reddit, somewhat inaccurate. It doesn't answer what they actually are.